# How do I post to GitHub API v3

Tags: c#, rest, oauth, github, github-api

I am using GitHub API v3 with C#. I am able to get the access token and using that I am able to get the user information and repo info.

**But when I try to create a new repo I am getting the error as Unauthorized.**

I am using HttpWebRequest to post data, which can be seen below. Please suggest me some C# sample or sample code.

```
(..)string[] paramName, string[] paramVal, string json, string accessToken)
{
    HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url)) as HttpWebRequest;
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "application/json";

    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
    writer.Write(json);
    writer.Close();

    string result = null;
    using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
        StreamReader reader =
            new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
        result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }(..)
```

Note: I am not sure where i need to add the accesstoken. I have tried in headers as well as in the url, but none of them works.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I got the same problem.

Comment: Note you probably just want to use this now : https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net or if you don't want all of it just copy the parts you do - it's a public github repo

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the [C# Github API example code](https://github.com/sgrassie/csharp-github-api)? I would look at that code to see if it does what you need.

Comment: No . I am not using that. Its "Very early stages of development. Only authentication is completed at this time."

Answer (score 3):

You can use basic auth pretty easily by just adding auth to the request headers:

```
request.Headers.Add("Authorization","Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(username +":"+password)));
```

Sorry havent used the access token stuff yet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this token here:

```
req.UserAgent = "My App";
req.Headers.Add("Authorization", string.Format("Token {0}", "..token..");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
rec.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

or use non-default credentials.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.credentials.aspx